# Image on top of UIlabel?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, addsubview

I'm trying to add title3 above the picture and into the black box on the left side.

Such as this

[image]

I'm not sure why it's not working but any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to Objective-C so if you see anything that I'm doing wrong or that could be done better don't hesitate to tell me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ChanelFeeds *currentFeed = [[xmlParser feeds] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90);
        self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
        [self.customImage release];


        // Title
        CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(122, 2, 198, 45);
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
        title.tag = 0011;
        title.numberOfLines = 2;
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
        [title release];

        // Views Placement
        CGRect contentFrame2 = CGRectMake(127, 70, 180, 15);
        UILabel *title2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame2];
        title2.tag = 0012;
        title2.numberOfLines = 1;
        title2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title2.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title2];
        [title2 release];



        //Here's where the fails come in

        NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *imgURL = [currentFeed thumbnailURL];
        NSArray *parts = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgURL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *imageName = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-2];

        NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

        UIImage  *myview = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        if(myview){
            cell.imageView.image = myview;

            //Add Black fucking border and stuff here!!!
        }else{


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[currentFeed thumbnailURL]];
                UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
                [self.feedsTableView beginUpdates];
                [self.feedsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]
                                           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [self.feedsTableView endUpdates];


            });
        }


        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(0, 67, 35, 13);
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];
        imv5.alpha = 1;
        imv5.tag = 0014;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];
        imv5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBorder.png"];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Formatting views
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  NSNumber * formattedViews = [f numberFromString
                                                                                                                                                  :[currentFeed views]]; [f release]; NSNumber *firstNumber = formattedViews; NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; convertedNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:firstNumber];


        // Basic stuff


        title.text = [currentFeed title];
        title2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views", convertedNumber];


        totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
        NSString *word = @":00:";
        NSString *word2 = @"00:00:";
        if ([totalTime rangeOfString:word].location == NSNotFound || [totalTime rangeOfString:word2].location != NSNotFound) {
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:00:" withString:@"0:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:" withString:@""];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"01:" withString:@"1:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"02:" withString:@"2:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"03:" withString:@"3:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"04:" withString:@"4:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"05:" withString:@"5:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"06:" withString:@"6:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"07:" withString:@"7:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"08:" withString:@"8:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"09:" withString:@"9:"];
        }

        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(4, 65, 60, 15);
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.tag = 0013;

        if([totalTime length] >= 5) {

            CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(4, 65, 60, 15);
            UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3.tag = 0013;
            title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
            title3.text = totalTime;
            [title3 release];
        } else {
            CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
            UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3.tag = 0013;
            title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
            title3.text = totalTime;
        }
        title3.numberOfLines = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];
        [title3 release];




    } else {
        //Update while scrolling

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  NSNumber * formattedViews = [f numberFromString
                                                                                                                                                  :[currentFeed views]]; [f release]; NSNumber *firstNumber = formattedViews; NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; convertedNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:firstNumber];









        // views and titles
        UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011];
        UILabel *title2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0012];

        title.text = [currentFeed title];
        title2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views", convertedNumber];









       totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
        NSString *word = @":00:";
        NSString *word2 = @"00:00:";
        if ([totalTime rangeOfString:word].location == NSNotFound || [totalTime rangeOfString:word2].location != NSNotFound) {
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:00:" withString:@"0:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:" withString:@""];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"01:" withString:@"1:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"02:" withString:@"2:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"03:" withString:@"3:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"04:" withString:@"4:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"05:" withString:@"5:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"06:" withString:@"6:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"07:" withString:@"7:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"08:" withString:@"8:"];
            totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"09:" withString:@"9:"];
        }
        UILabel *title3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0013];
        if([totalTime length] >= 5) {
            CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(4, 65, 60, 15);
            title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            title3.text = totalTime;
        } else {
            CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
            title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
            title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            title3.text = totalTime;
        }
        NSLog(@"%@ CHANGED TO : %@", [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1], totalTime);
    }





    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it is the root of this particular problem, but you are attempting to update the UI from a background thread, and that is not allowed.

After you load your thumbnail in the background you need to marshal the UI update calls back to the main thread.  Do this with another dispatch to the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`).